# Does useQuery refetch invalidates cache?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I would like to know if the refetch function that the useQuery hook returns invalidates the cache, since I need to retrieve the newest data from the resolver after a mutation is triggered. Is refetch enough or should I invalidate the cache manually?

`const { refetch } = useQuery(MY_QUERY)`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, yes: [client.refetchQueries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/refetching/#clientrefetchqueries) supports an explicit `updateCache` param.